# Modifying the library containing "labels"

Tags: dll, label

I want to replace the Windows DLL that contains the label object.  At first, I thought just each of the installs of the [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) would contain it, but some applications don't utilize the .NET Framework and still have labels.  I was wondering, what DLLs contain the label object?  Is there only one (like, at the top that they all reference)?  Do they all have it?